# VSCode MyPy error: "ioctl" has incompatible type "my_struct"; expected "Union[int, str]"

Tags: python, ctypes, mypy, ioctl

I have the following python snippet that is generating MyPy "problems" (in vscode).

```
my_struct = MyStruct()    
#! set mutable flag to true to place data in our object.
fcntl.ioctl( dev_hand.fileno(), my_ioctl_id, my_struct, True )
```

The error is:

**Argument 3 to "ioctl" has incompatible type "my_struct"; expected "Union[int, str]"**

MyStruct is a ctypes structure.  All the examples for using `ioctl()` with ctypes structures show passing the instance to `ioctl()`.  Indeed this does work, except now MyPy is complaining.

I'd prefer not to convert to bytes and manually pack/unpack with the `struct` module (which I presume is one solution).

I'm using `Python 3.7.3` on Linux (Debian Buster), with `mypy 0.782`

Thanks, Brendan.

---

NOTE: I forgot to mention that my code is targeting Python 2.7, as it is legacy from a Debian Jessie target system.  I am using the `--py2` switch for `mypy` (which must run on Python 3).

The `ioctl()` function has the following signature, which seems to come from the vscode server (remote ssh) ms-python .... typeshed/stdlib/3/fcntl.pyi`

```py
def ioctl(fd: _AnyFile,
          request: int,
          arg: Union[int, bytes] = ...,
          mutate_flag: bool = ...) -> Any: ...
```

Here is a more complete code example.

```py
from typing import ( BinaryIO, )

import ioctl
import fcntl

from ctypes import ( c_uint32, Structure, addressof )

class Point ( Structure ) :
    _fields_ = [ ( 'x', c_uint32 ), ( 'y', c_uint32 ) ]

def ioctl_get_point (
        dev_hand,
        ) :
    point = Point()
    fcntl.ioctl( dev_hand, 0x12345678, point, True )   #! ** MyPy does NOT complain at all **

def ioctl_get_point_2 (
        dev_hand,               # type: BinaryIO
        ) :
    point = Point()
    fcntl.ioctl( dev_hand, 0x12345678, point, True )   #! ** MyPy complains about arg 3 **
    return point

def ioctl_get_point_3 (
        dev_hand,
        ) :                     # type: (...) -> Point
    point = Point()
    fcntl.ioctl( dev_hand, 0x12345678, point, True )   #! ** MyPy complains about arg 3 **
    return point

def ioctl_get_point_4 (
        dev_hand,               # type: BinaryIO
        ) :                     # type: (...) -> Point
    point = Point()
    fcntl.ioctl( dev_hand, 0x12345678, point, True )   #! ** MyPy complains about arg 3 **
    return point

def ioctl_get_point_5 (
        dev_hand,               # type: BinaryIO
        ) :                     # type: (...) -> Point
    point = Point()
    fcntl.ioctl( dev_hand, 0x12345678, addressof( point ), True )   #! ** MyPy does NOT complain at all **
    return point
```

To me, it seems like using the `ctypes.addressof()` function, that @CristiFati suggested, is the simplest solution.

**Unfortunately that doesn't work.**  The `ioctl()` function needs to know the size of the object.

Thanks, Brendan.

Comment: `ctypes.addressof(my_struct)`?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're on Python 3.7.3, and running a Python 3 version of mypy? That looks like a Python 2 error message. (A Python 3 mypy would still give you an error message, but it'd be a different error message.)

Comment: Yes.  I am using mypy with python2 mode (`--py2`).  I've updated the question with more info.  I think CristiFati's answer of using `ctypes.addressof()` is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mypy` follows the specs of the [`fnctl.ioctl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.ioctl) function here:

> The parameter *arg* can be one of an integer, an object supporting the read-only buffer interface (like `bytes`) or an object supporting the read-write buffer interface (like `bytearray`).

The complaint is thus a legitimate one.

> I'd prefer not to convert to bytes and manually pack/unpack with the struct module

With the help of the [`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) constant, you can introduce a local stub with a type hint for `fnctl.ioctl` that will override stdlib's type hint:

```
import ctypes
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [...]


if TYPE_CHECKING:  # this is only processed by mypy
    from typing import Protocol, Union, TypeVar

    class HasFileno(Protocol):
        def fileno(self) -> int: ...

    FileDescriptorLike = Union[int, HasFileno]

    _S = TypeVar('_S', bound=ctypes.Structure)

    def ioctl(__fd: FileDescriptorLike, __request: int, __arg: Union[int, bytes, _S] = ..., __mutate_flag: bool = ...) -> int: ...

else:  # this will be executed at runtime and ignored by mypy
    from fcntl import ioctl


my_struct = MyStruct(...)
my_ioctl_id = ...
dev_hand = ...

ioctl(dev_hand.fileno(), my_ioctl_id, my_struct, True)  # mypy won't complain here anymore
```

Comment: ctypes structures *do* support the buffer interface, though, and strings don't! The online documentation contradicts the docstring and the signature perceived by mypy, and the [actual treatment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Modules/fcntlmodule.c#L174) of the argument seems to be a mix.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like a lot of work though.  I think CristiFati's answer of using ctypes.addressof() is the simplest solution.

Comment: so `ctypes.addressof()` wont work.  Makes sense as `ioctl()` needs to know the size of the object (and needs the buffer space for mutable return value).  Ok, I've looked at your solution again and makes more sense to me now.  I assume I can use that once and it will work for all sub-classes of Structure.  Going to give that a go.

Comment: I can confirm that this works and will be my accepted answer.  Thank you heaps !!

Answer (score 0):

First, that error message looks like a Python 2 mypy error message, not a Python 3 mypy error message. The [stubs](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/0142a87da886645c4a7186edcc71f7b3dcf8dc1e/stdlib/3/fcntl.pyi#L83-L92) for Python 3 have a declaration of `fcntl.ioctl` that doesn't match that error message. (You'd still get an error message with Python 3 mypy, but it'd be a different message.)

Second, `fcntl.ioctl` accepts any object that supports the buffer interface (including your struct), but mypy has no idea what the buffer interface even is. There is no annotation for an object that supports the buffer interface, and no way to statically recognize objects that support the buffer interface. It is currently *impossible* to correctly annotate functions like `fcntl.ioctl`. There are [open](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/593) [issues](https://bugs.python.org/issue27501) about this, but no resolution in sight.

Your best bet may be to slap a `# type: ignore` comment on that line.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes. I am using mypy with python2 mode (--py2). I've updated the question with more info. I think CristiFati's answer of using ctypes.addressof() is the simplest solution.